# Field operator in interacting theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory

I'm looking for any nontrivial scalar interacting toy theory for example in (1+1)D.

1) Does any $V(\phi)$ (not mass term) exist for which I can find explicit $a$ and $a^{+}$ as $F(\phi,\pi)$
2) Suppose I find ladder operators, how to write down field operator itself?
Since theory have interactions $$\phi(x)\neq\sum e^{-ipx}a_{p}+e^{ipx}a_{p}^{+} $$
Particles interact with each other so field is not decomposition over travelling plane wave profiles with ordinary energy momentum relation $E^2=\textbf{p}^2+m^2$.

3) What about vacuum? Because of 2) $$a|vac\rangle\neq a|0\rangle$$

4) Can I look on equation of motion $$(\Box+m^2 )\phi=-V'_{\phi}(\phi)$$ 
as on operator equation with condition $[\phi^{+}(x),\phi(x')]=0$ on space like separation? When it solvable? $V(\phi)$ should be normal ordered or it works only for free fields?

Any papers or neat examples?

Comment: Sine-gordon has ladder operators of sorts, since you have soliton solutions (and bounded solutions). The composition of two solitons isn't their sum, though.